# Area weighted average of wind speed gridded data using R

Tags: r

I have wind speed gridded data at a particular longitude and latitude. I want to calculate an area-weighted average of wind speed in R. I'm using the package "ClimProjDiags" for area-weighted average. Also, some code related to the area-weighted average was given.

```
data <- 1:(2 * 3 * 4 * 5)

dim(data) <- c(lon = 2, lat = 3, time = 4, model = 5)

lat <- c(1, 10, 20)

lon <- c(1, 10)

a <- WeightedMean(data = data, lon = lon, lat = lat, region = NULL, 
                 mask = NULL, londim = 1, latdim = 2)

str(a)
```

But here I do not understand what the time and model are representing.

Here is my data sample with longitude and latitude:

```
data <- c(3.632576,  3.226389, 5.810934, 4.473232, 3.239784)

lat = 5

lon = 79.59
```

How do I use my data sample in the above code to calculate an area-weighted average of wind speed gridded data?

Comment: I can't find a `ClimProjDiagSin` package. There's a `ClimProjDiags` on CRAN. Did you mean that?

Comment: `time` and `model` are extra dimensions in that data set. Then `WeightedMean` computes the average over all lat-longs for each time point for each model. If your data is just a simple grid of windspeed then it will compute the area-weighted average over the grid. Which is what you want?

Comment: Yes, the ClimProjDiags package is on CRAN.

Comment: I have gridded data with latitude and longitude. But I can not understand how to calculate the area-weighted average. Please provide me with some solution regarding this. I will be very grateful to you

Comment: You haven't shown us what your gridded data looks like. Have you got it in a matrix? Or a data frame? What columns? Do you know the lats and longs? Have you read the help for `WeightedMean` and got it in the right format for that function?

Comment: data <- c(3.632576,  3.226389, 5.810934, 4.473232, 3.239784)

lat = 5

lon = 79.59

Comment: Have you got four points *at the same location*? Then the mean is just the mean of `data`. The `WeightedMean` function is only for when you've got data across a grid of cells, because in lat-long each cell will have an area depending on its latitude, so you have to weight the mean to the larger cells.

Comment: You added a tag for QGIS but made no mention of how that is relevant to the question you are asking so I removed it.